# PySpark GroupBy + agg lambda with strings

Tags: pyspark, filter, group-by, aggregate

I am working with a dataset such as:

```
+------------+------+-----+
|     ADDRESS|  unit|count|
+------------+------+-----+
|           1|  203X|    4|
|           2|  203X|    1|
|           3|  302Z|    1|
|           2|  302Z|    4|
|           3|  203X|    3|
|           4|  302Z|    8|
|           1|  203X|    2|
|           2|  203X|    3|
|           2|  203X|    1|
|           5|  203X|    2|
+------------+------+-----+
```

I need to separately create three sets of data: 
1 & 2 which are a datasets containing addresses linked to unit LG203 and LG302, which is easy to do with a .filter function and: 
 3rd one which contains only those addresses that are linked to BOTH units at the same moment (eg. addresses 2 & 3 here). How can I filter my dataset alike? I tried to do: `ds.groupby(["ADDRESS"]).agg(lambda unit: "".join("unit"))` in order to make myself a third name '203X302Z' and then filter easier, but maybe someone has easier solution to my problem?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create a column that contains for 1 address the distinct list of units :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df.withColumn(
    "distinct_unit", F.collect_set("unit").over(Window.partitionBy("ADDRESS"))
).show()

+-------+----+-----+-------------+                                              
|ADDRESS|unit|count|distinct_unit|
+-------+----+-----+-------------+
|      5|203X|    2|       [203X]|
|      1|203X|    4|       [203X]|
|      1|203X|    2|       [203X]|
|      3|302Z|    1| [302Z, 203X]|
|      3|203X|    3| [302Z, 203X]|
|      2|203X|    1| [302Z, 203X]|
|      2|302Z|    4| [302Z, 203X]|
|      2|203X|    3| [302Z, 203X]|
|      2|203X|    1| [302Z, 203X]|
|      4|302Z|    8|       [302Z]|
+-------+----+-----+-------------+
```

---

Then work from here (with `F.size` for example to distinct which group you need to assign):

```py
df_group1 = df.where(F.col("unit") == "203X")
df_group2 = df.where(F.col("unit") == "302Z")
df_group3 = df.where(F.size(F.col("distinct_unit")) > 1)
```